# Some users cannot open my app after installing from google play store, how to check the cause?

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

I have an android app and one user from India with a Symphony phone says it gets crashed when he wants to open it. How do I get the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Crashlytics, it's a really helpful tool from firebase which help you get the stacktrace of any crash occurs when the app is published, here is a link for the docks [https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android]

Answer (score 0):

You can implements this library in your project and store the stacktrace on your own way:

https://github.com/Ereza/CustomActivityOnCrash